# missing tocstyle.sty file

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, tocstyle

I've recently installed Miktex, but when I try to edit a styles.sty file (which includes a toc), it gives  me the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tocstyle.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
:18: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.18 \usetocstyle
                 {standard}
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tocstyle` package is no longer part of MikTeX. From https://ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle:

> The package has been withdrawn from the koma-script bundle in Juli 2020 and is now considered obsolete. tocbasic and scrwfile should be used instead.

If you want to use it anyway, download the content from http://svn.code.sf.net/p/koma-script/code/trunk/obsolete/tocstyle-obsolete/, unpack it and add tocstyle.sty to your documents directory.

See also: https://www.komascript.de/release3.31

> Dieses Paket hat nie den Alpha-Status verlassen, war also immer nur eine Entwicklungsstudie. Es wurde auch immer davor gewarnt, dieses Paket für den produktiven Einsatz zu verwenden, da es jederzeit in seiner Funktion komplett verändert oder aus KOMA-Script entfernt werden kann. Viele Funktionen des Pakets wurden inzwischen tatsächlich in anderer Form in anderen Teilen von KOMA-Script, beispielsweise tocbasic oder scrwfile, implementiert. Das Paket ist daher ab KOMA-Script 3.31.3500 nicht mehr Teil der KOMA-Script-Sammlung. Auf CTAN wird es in das Paket KOMA-Script obsolete weiterhin verfügbar sein. Damit wird auch der Support durch mich, den es offiziell nie gab, vollends eingestellt.

Translation: This package has never left the alpha state and was always "development engineering". It has always been warned to use this package for productive environments since incompatible changes (or a complete removal) could always happen. Many features of this package are currently offered in supported packages like `tocbasic` or `scrwfile`. Therefore this package is not part of KOMA-Script 3.31.3500 anymore. It could still be found on CTAN, marked as obsolete, but there will be (still) no support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! It's because my friend uses MacTeX (I guess tocstyle is not obsolete there), but I was still wondering about the link u posted (http://svn.code.sf.net/p/koma-script/code/trunk/obsolete/tocstyle-obsolete/ -> do I copy paste the content of "tocstyle-obsolete.dtx" and put it in a tocstyle.sty file where my MikTeX project is located?

Comment: You could unpack `tocstyle-obsolete.dtx` to generate `tocstyle.sty` by processing the file `tocstyle-obsolete.dtx` with TeX. Note that TeX must be used, not LaTeX, otherwise it tries to generate a package documentation instead. (As an alternative just copy tocstyle.sty from your friends computer.)

Comment: You can download `koma-script-obsolete-3500.exe` from [KOMA-Scripts MiKTeX Archive Index](https://komascript.de/repository/miktex/). See also [Windows Installation Packages for MiKTeX](https://komascript.de/node/2051) and [Package Repositories](https://komascript.de/node/1801) on the KOMA-Script website.